# IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2 shows code completion ctrl+space hints and dissapear after 0.5 sec

Tags: intellij-idea, autocomplete, intellisense, javascript-intellisense

I'm working with **IDEA 2018.2**, and when I use **intellisense/autocomplete**, hints dissapears after about 0.5 sec. I use ctrl+space, see hints and I can't even read them all when it's gone.

It all started when I began new project in React Native, **in my Java projects everything works fine**.

I looked in Settings->Editor->Code Completion and didin't find anything.

Also I can mention that since i began React Native project, on my bottom bar file **indexation blinks** for a while every 2 sec.  (that's another problem for another topic, but it might be connected).

Comment: Try https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+2018.2+EAP.

Comment: please try invalidating caches (*File | Invalidate caches, Invalidate and restart*) - do both issue persist? If yes, please make sure to create a support ticket, providing your [log folder](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files) content

Comment: Update intelliJ fixed both problems, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CrazyCoder's solution fixed my problem.**

I updated my IntelliJ to newest version (**EAP**), and it resolved both problem, with blinking indexing and broken intellisense.

Reposting link for community: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/EAP

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem **File > Invalidate Caches / Restart** fixed it for me.